# Paged pool memory or Nonpaged pool memory ?? (windows driver development)

Tags: windows-xp, kernel, device-driver

I am newbie in windows driver development. I just want to know , a global variable in a driver will use paged pool memory or non paged pool memory  ?

Thanks and Regards

Navaneeth

Answer (score 8):

Depends. The Non paged pool should be reserved for memory that must stay in RAM so if you are doing something critical that would affected by a memory page from disk operation then use non paged.

See [here](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2009/03/26/3211216.aspx) for more info.

Looking at [this](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/driver/kernel/KMcode.mspx) (though it discusses c++ as opposed to C) it would seem that by default the globals can be located in either by #pragma. Also on p22 of [this](http://people.msoe.edu/~atassim/atassi_WDM.pdf)  we see how to do this. Finally [this discuss](http://www.osronline.com/showThread.cfm?link=27690) here we see that the data segment should be non pagagable by default.

Comment: No.my question is somthing like  if i declare a global variable in device driver,which memory will be used ,ie paged pool memory or non-paged pool memory?(Local variable will use non paged pool memory).

Comment: it wont be depends.

it will be either paged or non-paged pool.

Comment: #pragma data_seg("PAGE") int foo; #pragma data_seg("NONPAGE") int bar; -- foo here is pageable, and bar is non-paged. The default is non-paged if you don't give it a pragma.

Answer (score 2):

Global variables in a kernel mode driver are allocated from NonPagedPool.

You can also use the device extension (when you call IoCreateDevice), it is always allocated from NonPaged memory.

I hope this helps,
Martin

Comment: This isn't true. Kernel drivers in Windows are PE files with multiple sections, and unlike normal user-mode programs, KM drivers normally have *two* data-sections - one that is paged and one that is non-paged (and occasionally a third which is discarded after the KM driver has initialized). In your code you can choose whether your  variable (or indeed function) is paged or non-paged through the use of the alloc pragmas.

Answer (score 0):

Another good answer that I find is: "Nonpaged pool is kernel memory which can't be paged out into the pagefile when Windows runs out of free physical memory. It is used by drivers to allocate memory which they need." from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/590441/what-is-nonpaged-pool)