# Linux version of Windows "nonpaged pool" does such a thing exist?

Tags: linux, performance, network-programming, kernel

I have been working with an Windows application which reads from the 'nonpaged pool' to increase performance. In this case the nonpaged pool is the area of memory where the network drivers write data as they grab it off the wire.

How does Linux handle memory which network drivers (or other drivers) which require high speed exclusive access to RAM and does the question 'how do I read directly from nonpaged pool?' even make sense when applied to Linux?

Many thanks

[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796848/paged-pool-memory-or-nonpaged-pool-memory-windows-driver-development)

Comment: Do you mean a driver which uses non-paged pool? Windows does not provide access to non-paged pool to applications - it is a kernel only thing.

Comment: The application only reads from non-paged pool, occasionally not fast enough!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some networks like Infiniband support RDMA, which requires being able to prevent paging for some of the pages in a process. See the mlock(), mlockall(), munlock(), munlockall() functions.

Other than that, I don't think there is a concept of "nonpaged pool", per se. Generally, kernel memory is AFAIK not pageable, but all user memory except that locked with mlock() or such is.